# Efficient R code for finding indices associated with unique values in vector

Tags: r, list, vector, unique, data.table

Suppose I have vector `vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")`.

My objective is to end up with a list of dimension `length(unique(vec))`, where each `i` of this list returns a vector of indices which denote the locations of `unique(vec)[i]` in `vec`.

For example, this list for `vec` would return:

```
exampleList <- list()
exampleList[[1]] <- c(1) #Since "D" is the first element
exampleList[[2]] <- c(2,3) #Since "B" is the 2nd/3rd element.
exampleList[[3]] <- c(4,5) #Since "C" is the 4th/5th element.
```

I tried the following approach but it's too slow. My example is large so I need faster code:

```
vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")
uniques <- unique(vec)
exampleList <- lapply(1:3,function(i) {
    which(vec==uniques[i])
})
exampleList
```

Comment: In case anyone comes here looking for the unique indices as a vector (rather than a list), it's simply: `order(vec)[!duplicated(sort(vec))]` where `vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** The behaviour `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` sometimes resulted in wrong results in R version >= 3.1.0. This is now fixed in [commit #1280](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/86276f48798491d328caa72f6ebcce4d51649440) in the current development version of [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> - `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` returns correct results in R >=3.1.0 as well. The bug was due to recent (welcoming) changes in R v3.1.0 where `list(.)` does not result in a *copy*. Closes [#481](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/481).

---

Using `data.table` is about 15x faster than `tapply`:

```
library(data.table)

vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")

dt = as.data.table(vec)[, list(list(.I)), by = vec]
dt
#   vec  V1
#1:   D   1
#2:   B 2,3
#3:   C 4,5

# to get it in the desired format
# (perhaps in the future data.table's setnames will work for lists instead)
setattr(dt$V1, 'names', dt$vec)
dt$V1
#$D
#[1] 1
#
#$B
#[1] 2 3
#
#$C
#[1] 4 5
```

Speed tests:

```
vec = sample(letters, 1e7, T)

system.time(tapply(seq_along(vec), vec, identity)[unique(vec)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   7.92    0.35    8.50 

system.time({dt = as.data.table(vec)[, list(list(.I)), by = vec]; setattr(dt$V1, 'names', dt$vec); dt$V1})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.39    0.09    0.49
```

Comment: @Arun good point, thanks! somewhat to my surprise it didn't affect the timings at all - I guess this is just too cheap to copy

Comment: Interesting ... I get different results with your data.table code: dt in my computer becomes > dt
   vec  V1
1:   D 4,5
2:   B 4,5
3:   C 4,5 (- that is, all elements of V1 are equally 4:5).

Comment: @lebatsnok what version of `data.table` are you running? (I'm using 1.9.3)

Comment: I have 1.9.2 - should it be different in 1.9.3? (in addition I get different results with tapply and data.table versions above..)

Comment: @lebatsnok works fine with 1.9.2 for me - try a clean session

Comment: it still refuses to work for me .. the most simple example with `vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")` gives me dt$V1 with all elements == 4:5. Using R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330) on ubuntu (but still data.table 1.9.2 - for some reason, it won't install R 1.9.3 on my system)

Comment: there must be something going on with data.table in linux. I just tried exactly the same code on a windows machine and the result is exactly as in your example. with data.table 1.9.2 and R version 3.0.2

Comment: @lebatsnok it works for me on linux as well, maybe it has to do with your R version (I'm running R 3.0.1 and 3.0.2)? Might be worth bring this up as a bug on R-forge.

Comment: you're right, it's probably R version. just tried and it works on R 3.0.3 on debian. (this is about the second time i hear about r-forge, thanks for the indication)

Comment: @lebatsnok, this is due to recent `R-3.1.0` behaviour. `list(.)` doesn't copy anymore (welcome change). Should've been caught. Seems like this one slipped away because there's no test for this scenario. Work around for now is : `dt[, list(copy(list(.I))), by=vec]` or `dt[, list(list(copy(.I))), by=vec]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
split(seq_along(vec), vec)
```

this is faster and shorter than tapply solution:

```
vec = sample(letters, 1e7, T)
system.time(res1 <- tapply(seq_along(vec), vec, identity)[unique(vec)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.808   0.364   2.176 
system.time(res2 <- split(seq_along(vec), vec))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.876   0.152   1.029
```

Comment: bah.. I didn't notice this was already suggested in a comment above  `A similar approach could be: split(seq_along(vec), vec) –  alexis_laz 3 hours ago `

Comment: The only approach that works with numbers instead of letters.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `tapply`:

```
vec <- c("D", "B", "B", "C", "C")
tapply(seq_along(vec), vec, identity)[unique(vec)]
# $D
# [1] 1
# 
# $B
# [1] 2 3
# 
# $C
# [1] 4 5
```

The `identity` function returns its argument as its result, and indexing by `unique(vec)` ensures you get it back in the same order of the elements in your original vector.

Comment: It's kind of ridiculous how fast this function is.

Comment: How do I get it so it focuses on the ordering of elements in stead of alphabetical ordering? My use case requires ordering of elements and not alphabetical ordering (e.g. `vec <- c("C","B")` should return `$C [1] 1   $B [1] 2` instead of the other way around).

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm looking for in my original post.

Comment: @user2763361 I updated so it matches the ordering in the original vector.

Comment: A similar approach could be: `split(seq_along(vec), vec)`

Comment: @alexis_laz great point -- and `microbenchmark` seems to think that's about 2x quicker.

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the order of josilber's answer, simply index the result by the `uniques` vector you created:

```
vec <- c("D","B","B","C","C")

uniques <- unique(vec)

tapply(seq_along(vec), vec, identity)[uniques]

# $D
# [1] 1
#
# $B
# [1] 2 3
#
# $C
# [1] 4 5
```